# How to get the type of a property used within a generic expression?

Tags: c#, generics, expression, expression-trees

```
public static void Map<T>(Expression<Func<T, object >> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = (expression.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression;
    var name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<Article>(x => x.Name)
```

**Name** is of type string.

How do I get the type?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work for me. `x.Name` is not a `UnaryExpression`. Also, you shouldn't use `as` the way you do. If the cast doesn't succeed, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`, which is not good, getting `InvalidCastException` is much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var returnType = memberExpression.Member is MethodInfo 
    ? ((MethodInfo)memberExpression.Member).ReturnType 
    : ((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member).PropertyType;
```

I assume you want the return type.  If you want the type on which the method is defined, use `memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType`.

Comment: memberExpression.Member is of type MemberInfo and cant be casted to MethodInfo.

Comment: MemberInfo is the base class of MethodInfo and PropertyInfo.  In your case, I guess it's a PropertyInfo.  In that case, use `var returnType = ((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member).PropertyType;`  But since you'll never quite know which one it is, you'll have to test.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it will always be a property (and not a field), you can do it like this:

```
public static void Map<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
    var name = property.Name.Dump();
    var type = property.PropertyType.Dump();
}
```

This also fixes the error I mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Expression Extension Method that may be useful to others.

```
 public static Type GetPropertyType<TModel, TValue>(this Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        }
        return ((PropertyInfo)body.Member).PropertyType;
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
if (expression.GetPropertyType() == typeof(DateTime))
```

Answer (score -3):

Shouldn't be too difficult:

`x.Name.GetType()`

Comment: I want to get the type within the Map method.